# Named range with colors

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, named-ranges

I have one sheet with status like that:

**Status**
S1
S2
...
S10

And each one have a different color.

I'm using a named range on that status list in several places.
Is there a way that force that not only the name will be copied but also there colors for all the places I'm using?

I can work with conditional format, but that mean that the definition is where I use the named range (which is several places) rather where I define it (one place).

Comment: how are you copying the data? The cell color should be copied unless you are pasting as values or similar.

Comment: I'm not copying. I've create a NamedRange of the values. And I'm using this NamedRange in order to provide a selection from a closed list of only those values. but when doing so, I'm getting the values without the format. Is there a way to get them with the format?

Comment: its not possible, named ranges are a good alternative or VBA.

Answer (score 0):

A bit long for a comment.

> Is there a way that force that not only the name will be copied but also there colors for all the places I'm using?

"copied" yes, that is the default behaviour (as @InContext)
referenced (ie "I'm not copying"), I think not (without something like VBA).

> I can work with conditional format, but that mean that the definition is where I use the named range (which is several places) rather where I define it (one place).

I think not. With Conditional Formatting the defining of conditions is not done within a cell but in Rules Manager. One rule (say "Format only cells that contain" "Specific Text" " containing" `S2`) can be applied to a cell but can alternatively be applied to a range of cells.

The trigger value (`S2` in the above example) is valid whether input as a string or output by a formula.

Simple test, add as many `S2`'s as desired within A1:Z100 of a new sheet and apply:

[image: S25115213 example]

The above rule will highlight cells that contain the likes of `x S2 h` but choice of a different rule could restrict the highlighting to cells that show only `S2`.